# AssertionError: Specified args not emitted - Solidity Hardhat

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, solidity, hardhat

I have a smart contract that I'm testing the first functions of, and so far everything seems fine apart from one argument of an event not being properly passed.

The contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

// contract that mints 10 NFTs that will then be sold on the market place

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MintNFT is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {

    //Helpers
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    string[] public _allTokenURIs;
    mapping(uint256 => string) public _IDtoURI;

    event NFTMinted(uint256 indexed tokenId, string uri);
    
    constructor() ERC721("Plot On Mars", "POM") {}


    function bulkMint(string[] memory uris)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _allTokenURIs = uris;
        address to = msg.sender;
        for (uint i = 0; i < uris.length; i++) {
            safeMint(to, uris[i]);
        }
    }

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri)
        internal
        onlyOwner
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
        _IDtoURI[tokenId]=uri;
        emit NFTMinted(tokenId, uri);
    }


    function getTokenId() public view returns(uint256){
        return _tokenIds.current();
    }


    // function to view a specific URI related to a tokenID
    function viewURIs(uint256 i) public view returns(string memory){
        string memory unique = _allTokenURIs[i];
        return unique;
    }


     // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

}
```

The test script :

```
const { assert, expect, expectEvent } = require("chai")
const { network, deployment, ethers, deployments } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

//Arrange-Act-Assert (AAA)
// if we have defined an error in our solidity code, we must wrap the logic corresponding
//in a catch/try{}

//skip test if on localhost/hardhat
!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  ? describe.skip
  : describe("Basic NFT minting tests", function () {
      let mintNFT, deployer
      let _name = "Plot On Mars"
      let _symbol = "POM"
      let tokensUris = [
        "ipfs://QmaGmVJianGd3wzdfRNFZXWA9UeMdLFMBX5cZZSZjNeckP",
        "ipfs://QmaGV6P2knFkPdStvPsNXjJjehEysfnK7e4tShJAvpuPrx",
        "ipfs://QmcdbzSUFhRF98ppNHf83yhPJ2jHjP5Lpuov9Wzi4aYZF4",
        "ipfs://QmP8W1KEC2td2VPn3tbEYjFBZ2yV6jZh5Fbe2rGjzqCMwS",
        "ipfs://QmdL2QjcLPjd1RLwHK1GNuNQSt5b4ZXupuaGYtUi3Lqqz5",
        "ipfs://QmaJqsMKbFLLTZszY2rprPRncDReLTnhHVdz2U7aScxFNS",
        "ipfs://QmYeioLfMcTUNSABndwqJz7sjaeA7quF1fMGq2tziSE2T3",
        "ipfs://QmW7nRHE7J5L36n9NvxspwNfSbEPRcFvDF4kUkscZHehyZ",
        "ipfs://QmUcCwpskbvQydNa3rcSpCftsPAmBgovn6WnZYTeZw4NpU",
        "ipfs://QmdyTVfRymf2kFrrfdNq2FGHYX4gx5YDT1DvgmkccSee1U",
      ]

      //deploys the contract and gets an instance of it to work with
      beforeEach(async () => {
        accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        deployer = accounts[0]
        user = accounts[1]
        await deployments.fixture(["mintnft"])
        mintNFT = await ethers.getContract("MintNFT")
      })

      // constructor
      describe("Deployment", function () {
        it("Should have the correct name and symbol", async function () {
          expect(await mintNFT.name()).to.equal(_name)
          expect(await mintNFT.symbol()).to.equal(_symbol)
        })
        it("should set the right owner", async function () {
          expect(await mintNFT.owner()).to.equal(deployer.address)
        })
      })

      // bulkMint()
      describe("It mints 10NFTs", function () {
        it("Should be reverted as caller is not owner", async function () {
          await expect(mintNFT.connect(user).bulkMint(tokensUris)).to.be.revertedWith(
            "Ownable: caller is not the owner"
          )
        })
        it("Should emit the NFtMinted event after each token minted", async function () {
          for (i = 0; i < tokensUris.length; i++) {
            let index = i
            await expect(mintNFT.bulkMint(tokensUris))
              .to.emit(mintNFT, "NFTMinted")
              .withArgs(tokensUris[i], index)
          }
        })

        describe("View token ID to check that counter is at 10", function () {
          let tokencounter = 10
          it("Should return a token counter of 10 if all NFTs have been successfully minted", async function () {
            await mintNFT.bulkMint(tokensUris)
            expect(await mintNFT.getTokenId()).to.equal(tokencounter)
          })
        })

        //after calling buklMint(), grab the tokenURIs and test them individually = getURI(0)="ipfs://..."
        describe("Each token URI is properly initialized", function () {
          it("Should set the token URIs to their correct ipfs addresses", async function () {
            await mintNFT.bulkMint(tokensUris)
            //assumes that the bulkMint() is correctly working. If it is, it will initialize _allTokenURIs and viewUris() will return them
            for (i = 0; i < tokensUris.length; i++) {
              expect(await mintNFT.viewURIs(i)).to.equal(tokensUris[i])
              console.log(await mintNFT.viewURIs(i), "is equal to", tokensUris[i])
            }
          })
        })
      })
    })
```

When running tests, here are the results :

```
anne@AnneSager:~/HAAAAAAAA/newTry$ yarn hardhat test
yarn run v1.22.15
warning package.json: No license field
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ /home/anne/HAAAAAAAA/newTry/node_modules/.bin/hardhat test
Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully


  Basic NFT minting tests
    Deployment
      ✔ Should have the correct name and symbol (40ms)
      ✔ should set the right owner
    It mints 10NFTs
      ✔ Should be reverted as caller is not owner (74ms)
      1) Should emit the NFtMinted event after each token minted
      View token ID to check that counter is at 10
        ✔ Should return a token counter of 10 if all NFTs have been successfully minted (174ms)
      Each token URI is properly initialized
ipfs://QmaGmVJianGd3wzdfRNFZXWA9UeMdLFMBX5cZZSZjNeckP is equal to ipfs://QmaGmVJianGd3wzdfRNFZXWA9UeMdLFMBX5cZZSZjNeckP
ipfs://QmaGV6P2knFkPdStvPsNXjJjehEysfnK7e4tShJAvpuPrx is equal to ipfs://QmaGV6P2knFkPdStvPsNXjJjehEysfnK7e4tShJAvpuPrx
ipfs://QmcdbzSUFhRF98ppNHf83yhPJ2jHjP5Lpuov9Wzi4aYZF4 is equal to ipfs://QmcdbzSUFhRF98ppNHf83yhPJ2jHjP5Lpuov9Wzi4aYZF4
ipfs://QmP8W1KEC2td2VPn3tbEYjFBZ2yV6jZh5Fbe2rGjzqCMwS is equal to ipfs://QmP8W1KEC2td2VPn3tbEYjFBZ2yV6jZh5Fbe2rGjzqCMwS
ipfs://QmdL2QjcLPjd1RLwHK1GNuNQSt5b4ZXupuaGYtUi3Lqqz5 is equal to ipfs://QmdL2QjcLPjd1RLwHK1GNuNQSt5b4ZXupuaGYtUi3Lqqz5
ipfs://QmaJqsMKbFLLTZszY2rprPRncDReLTnhHVdz2U7aScxFNS is equal to ipfs://QmaJqsMKbFLLTZszY2rprPRncDReLTnhHVdz2U7aScxFNS
ipfs://QmYeioLfMcTUNSABndwqJz7sjaeA7quF1fMGq2tziSE2T3 is equal to ipfs://QmYeioLfMcTUNSABndwqJz7sjaeA7quF1fMGq2tziSE2T3
ipfs://QmW7nRHE7J5L36n9NvxspwNfSbEPRcFvDF4kUkscZHehyZ is equal to ipfs://QmW7nRHE7J5L36n9NvxspwNfSbEPRcFvDF4kUkscZHehyZ
ipfs://QmUcCwpskbvQydNa3rcSpCftsPAmBgovn6WnZYTeZw4NpU is equal to ipfs://QmUcCwpskbvQydNa3rcSpCftsPAmBgovn6WnZYTeZw4NpU
ipfs://QmdyTVfRymf2kFrrfdNq2FGHYX4gx5YDT1DvgmkccSee1U is equal to ipfs://QmdyTVfRymf2kFrrfdNq2FGHYX4gx5YDT1DvgmkccSee1U
        ✔ Should set the token URIs to their correct ipfs addresses (383ms)


  5 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Basic NFT minting tests
       It mints 10NFTs
         Should emit the NFtMinted event after each token minted:
     AssertionError: Specified args not emitted in any of 10 emitted "NFTMinted" events
  



error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've run the same code with only changing the arguments in the `NFTMinted` event, passing it only the `uri` variable, and the 6 tests passed successfully.

So my problem comes from my `tokenId`... I've tried not using `Counters` and initializing my own `uint256 tokenId`, but the error was the same, `AssertionError: Specified args not emitted in any of 10 emitted "NFTMinted" events`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Other info:

- package.json :

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.7.2",
    "@pinata/sdk": "^1.1.26",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.6.9",
    "hardhat": "^2.10.1",
    "hardhat-contract-sizer": "^2.6.1",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.12",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.0.0-dev.23",
    "solhint": "^3.3.7",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.7.21"
  }
}
```

- running on Linux Ubuntu 20.4
- using VSCode

***UPDATE***

Derawi's comment made me run through my code again to try to figure out how to not call the `bulkMint()` function 10 times.
I have not managed to fix it yet, but the changes I made brought a new error that allows me to push my thought process forward.

**Changes**
modified my `bulkMint()`

```
function bulkMint(string[] memory uris)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _allTokenURIs = uris;
        address to = msg.sender;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _allTokenURIs.length; i++) {
            string memory uri = _allTokenURIs[i];
            safeMint(to, uri);
        }
    }
```

`mint-unit.js` test file :

```
describe("It mints 10NFTs", function () {
        it("Should be reverted as caller is not owner", async function () {
          await expect(mintNFT.connect(user).bulkMint(tokensUris)).to.be.revertedWith(
            "Ownable: caller is not the owner"
          )
        })
        it("Should emit the NFtMinted event after each token minted", async function () {
          await mintNFT.bulkMint(tokensUris)
          for (i = 0; i < tokensUris.length; i++) {
            let index = i
            let uri = tokensUris[index]
            await expect(mintNFT.safeMint(deployer.address, uri))
              .to.emit(mintNFT, "NFTMinted")
              .withArgs(index, uri)
          }
        })
```

Now the error message is :

```
1) Basic NFT minting tests
       It mints 10NFTs
         Should emit the NFtMinted event after each token minted:
     AssertionError: Expected "11" to be equal 0
      at assertArgsArraysEqual (node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/chai/dist/cjs/matchers/emit.js:58:54)
      at tryAssertArgsArraysEqual (node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/chai/dist/cjs/matchers/emit.js:65:20)
      at /home/anne/HAAAAAAAA/newTry/node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/chai/dist/cjs/matchers/emit.js:77:13
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/mint-unit.js:61:13)
```

Any help is still appreciated, I can tell I've messed somewhere, but still can't figure out if it's on the contract, on the test, or on both :/

Comment: could it be that you are calling bulk mint 10 times, but are comparing it to a single uri?

this line:            await expect(mintNFT.bulkMint(tokensUris))

Comment: @Derawi I've tried to build my code so that I call bulkMint() only once, passing it an array of strings, and the bulkMint() calls safeMint() 10 times, passing it one string of the strings array. I'm still new to this, so please show me where I've made this mistake more in details :)